# 'exclude' but don't ignore result?

Tags: django

I have a `ModelForm` with two integer fields, `x` and `y`. These correspond to coordinates on an image. For our non-JS users, when inputting data I've supplied an `input` with `type=image`. This type of input sends the `x` and `y` of where it was clicked.

The problem is that if I `exclude` x and y in my form, the results from the clicked image are not processed. If I don't exclude them, they are processed correctly, but two text inputs are shown. What should I do so that the form doesn't display x and y fields, but doesn't ignore the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    hidden_widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['hidden_field'] = forms.CharField(widget=hidden_widget)
```

Comment: self.fields['hidden_field'].widget.attrs = {'class':'hide_this_field'}
Something like this could also work, using css to hide the field.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the offical docs , If I remember correctly but this should work.
Render both fields as hidden:

```
{{ form.field_name.as_hidden }}
```

You could also set it's widget to a hidden field (HidenInput): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: How do I assign widgets in a ModelForm?

Comment: @Tom Medley -- check out [assigning widgets in ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets).